# Is there an efficient way to find the closest match of a subset of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to map two Dataframes based on a timewindow and a mass.

They look something like this:

```
df_quant = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [590.817776, 1837.124783, 10657784],
        [513.312719, 1746.827691, 1065876],
        [581.317391, 1773.417336, 368741]],
    columns=["mass", "time", "amount"])

        
df_ID = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [590.817778, 1839.124781, "1"],
        [513.312721, 1745.827690, "2"],
        [581.317396, 1771.417339, "3"]],
    columns=["mass", "time", "ID"])
```

Note that the "time" and "mass" columns are float values and not exactly the same in the two dataframes.

What I want to achieve, is to take the "time" column from df_quant and match its "mass" to the closest "mass" entry in df_ID in a "time" range of +/- 9 seconds.

So far I have a working solution with the apply() method. However, for a large Dataframe it is way too slow.

What I have so far is:

```
def map_quant_ID(mass, time, df_ID):   
    
    time_low = time - 9
    time_high = time + 9

    df_ID_sorted = df_ID.sort_values(by=["time"]).reset_index(drop=True)
    df_ID_sorted = df_ID_sorted[(df_ID_sorted["time"] > time_low) & (df_ID_sorted["time"] < time_high)]

    df_ID_sorted = df_ID_sorted.sort_values(by=["mass"]).reset_index(drop=True)

    index = np.searchsorted(df_ID_sorted["mass"], mass)
    
    return df_ID_sorted.loc[index, "ID"] 

df_quant["ID"] = df_quant.apply(lambda row: map_quant_ID(row["mass"], row["time"], df_ID), axis=1)
```

Does anyone have a working (vectorized) solution for this kind of problem?

Any input is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A _vectorized solution_ using Pandas? I don't think so, How big is the data?

Comment: Usually between 100-200k rows in df_quant and a fiew thousand in df_ID.

Comment: Are you only looking for a solution using Pandas? or are you open to alternatives as well?

Comment: have you tried `pd.merge_asof`, with the tolerance parameter?

Comment: @Luce I am also open for alternatives, if I understand them

Comment: @sammywemmy It seems that I have to convert the "mass" column to int64 to get it to work. Then the results look promising thanks for that. Is there a way I can reduce information loss due to the conversion?